# How do I call the list of future variables?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

It is necessary to read the collection, and the collection. One person said that you need to read them separately through Future.await. But my code throws an error. Please help me what needs to be done so that I can upload several collections into one.dart file?

```
class Checking extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "Checking";

  @override
  State<Checking> createState() => _CheckingState();
}

class _CheckingState extends State<Checking> {
  Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getthosedocuments() async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('testfz')
        //.doc('oglavlenie')
        //.collection('subcollection')
    //.limit(1)
        .get();
    return snapshot;

  }

  Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getthosedocuments1() async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('testfz')
        .doc('id')
        .collection('subcollection')
    //.limit(1)
        .get();
    return snapshot;

  }


void futures() async {
  var futures = await Future.wait([getthosedocuments(), getthosedocuments1()]);
}




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          future: futures(),
          builder: (context, snapshotsub) {
            if (snapshotsub.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            final docs = snapshotsub.data!.docs;

            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: snapshotsub.data?.size,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final doc = docs.elementAt(index);
```

The error that I get:

> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```dart
void futures() async {
  var futures = await Future.wait([getthosedocuments(), getthosedocuments1()]);
}
```

with

```dart
Future<List<QuerySnapshot>> get futures => Future.wait([getthosedocuments(), getthosedocuments1()]);
```

Then inside future builder, you should expect List instead of QuerySnapshot.

Comment: Then I get an error of this nature if I change it to List
The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'List<dynamic>'.
The getter 'size' isn't defined for the type 'List<dynamic>'.

Comment: change `Future.wait` to `Future<QuerySnapshot>.wait`

Comment: The problem was not solved :(

Error:
A value of type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>' can't be returned from the function 'futures' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>'.
The class 'Future' doesn't have a constructor named 'wait'.